# Calling GUI to take input inside the for loop Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am running a script which has a for loop. Inside for loop I am calling GUI. The GUI displays 3 figures when it opens up. Then it has a pushbutton which is used for taking input from the GUI.

When I am running it, it iterates without taking input and so I am not able to take input.
I used uiwait and uiresume but they didn't work (May be because I am not able to use it).

Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thanks

This is demo code:
Script:

```
for i=1:5  
    tp1(i)  
end
```

GUI:

```
function tp1_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

handles.output = hObject;  
global j  
guidata(hObject, handles);  
i=varargin{1};  
set(handles.edit1,'String',num2str(i));    



function edit2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)  
global t;    
t=get(hObject,'String');    


function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)  
global t  
t  
close('gcbf')
```

This is code snippet.

In gui I have 2 edit box. edit1 is for output and edit2 is for taking input.

Comment: Too vague, either post a code snippet or explain what you expect to happen with this input.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the button's callback knows where to place the user input in order to be found by the other functions... If yes, try something like this to make your program wait:

```
h = msgbox(                         ...
    'Close this when you''re done', ...
    'The user interface says...',   ...
    'help', 'non-modal'             ...
);
uiwait(h);
```